# Triangle with two medians

Tags: geometry, triangles

I need help with this proof:

AD and BE are medians in triangle ABC, meeting at point F. Point G is the middle of segment BF. The continuation of the segment AG intersects the side BC at point H. Prove that BC=5BH.

[image: Triangle2Medians]

Here's what I could find:

- AD=DC
- BE=EC
- BG=GF=FE
- ED || AB

However I don't see how these facts help me prove the claim.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks. I added the facts I could discover myself so far. Hope that now it's ok.

Comment: Are you sure $AD = DC$ and $BE = EC$?

Comment: Until you explain how you found $AD=DC$ and $BE=EC$, it is difficult to help you. To solve this problem, you need to draw one auxiliary line segment.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Line $AH$ is a transversal of $\triangle BCE.$ Now apply [Menelaus' Theorem.](https://brilliant.org/wiki/menelaus-theorem/#:%7E:text=Menelaus%27%20theorem%20relates%20ratios%20obtained,that%20three%20points%20are%20collinear.)

> $$\frac{CA}{EA}\cdot \frac{EG}{GB}\cdot \frac{BH}{HC}=1\implies 2\cdot 2\cdot \frac{BH}{BC-BH}=1\implies 5\cdot BH=BC$$

Comment: Thanks. I guess it can help, but I don't think that we've learned Menalaus theorem, so I guess they expect a different solution...

Comment: @ArnonAxelrod Then you should state what you know / are expected to try. EG There is a coordinate geometry solution, so could you at least do that?

Comment: @JeanMarie $(CA/EA)\times (EG/GB)\times (BH/HC)=1.$ Is this incorrect ?

Comment: You are right, my bad, I hadn't applied Menelaus with the right transversal. I erase my comment. Maybe, it is good to include this equality in your answer because it is not evident for somebody who uses Menelaus for the first time...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the fact that the cross-ratio of four aligned points is preserved under a perspective (one of the fundamental properties of "projective geometry"), here the perspective sending $B \to B, G \to H, F \to D, E \to C$ :

$$\underbrace{\frac{BE}{BG}\times\frac{FG}{FE}}_{= 3 \times 1}=\frac{BC}{BH}\times\frac{DH}{DC}\tag{1}$$

(The value of the LHS is a consequence of relationship $BG=GF=FE$ you have remarked).

Let us take coordinates on line $BC$ such that :

$$ B=0, \ \ H=h, \ \ D=1, \ \ C=2.\tag{2}$$

Therefore, (1) becomes :

$$3=\frac{2}{h}\frac{1 - h}{1}$$

a first degree equation giving $h=\frac25$

As a consequence, using (2) again :

$$\frac{BC}{BH}=\frac{2}{h}=5.$$

Comment: Any comment ?...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Notice: points are renamed.

Considering figure:

$FG=\frac12 AG$

and $HI||GO||FN\Rightarrow AI=IO=ON$

Also:

$EG=\frac12 GB$

and $EO||GN||LM$

where L is mid point of GB, so we have:

$ON=NM=MB$

Therfore:

$AI=IO=ON=NM=MB$

that is $AI=\frac15 AB$